# decrease key operation in Fibonacci heap searching the key is require or not

Tags: data-structures

In Fibonacci heap Decrease key operation how the key node is identified.

Everywhere the amortized cost for the operation given as O(1) but before decrease key the key node should be identified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to locate the node before you can decrease its key. Typically that's done by implementing a separate data structure that maps keys to heap nodes. That lookup can be done in O(1) time.

Otherwise, locating an arbitrary node in a heap is an O(n) operation.